# Normalization UNF to 1NF

Tags: database, database-normalization

When normalizing a relation with multi-value attributes, we decompose it as a new relation with the primary key field and the values from the multi-valued attribute.

The problem I have is, what is the primary key for that newly created attribute?

If we use the same old primary key as the new one, since we repeat the values there with the values from the multi-valued attribute, how can we have unique values for the primary key field here?

I have a table with customer_names, their hobbies and so on. Some people have more than 1 hobby, so now it's a multi-valued attribute. Now even if I create a new relation only with customer_name & one hobby at a time, how can I add details of the people say who have 3 hobbies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the lookup table for the new attribute, you don't repeat the value in the lookup table.  And usually you add an artificial PK in the form of an IDENTITY column.

For example:   You have a table with a bunch of addresses.   There are many addresses with a common city.

You decide to normalize by creating a city table.  You only add a given city to the City table ONCE.   Not once for each address.

EDIT:  in the scenario described in your comment, you could create a `Hobbies` table with `CustomerID` and `HobbyName`.

`CustomerID` would be a foreign key that references the Primary Key in the `Customers` table.

EDIT 2:  As Beth and I mentioned in comments, it seems you want a many-to-many relationship.

Create a `Hobbies` table, which has only one row per unique Hobby.  If two or more customers have the same Hobby, you still only list the hobby in the table once.  Use an Identity column to create a `HobbyID` as the Primary Key.

Then create a `CustomerHobby` table.   It has `CustomerID` and `HobbyID`.   Both are foreign keys that reference the primary keys of the `Customers` table and `Hobbies` table, respectively.

That's it.

Comment: The situation I want to know here is I have a table with customer_name their hobbies and so on.Some people have more than 1 hobbies,so now it's a multi valued attribute.  Now even if I create a new relation only with customer_name & one hobby at a time, how can I add details of the people say who have 3 hobbies! Please help me

Comment: Can more than one person have the same hobby?   If so, then you might want to create a many-to-many relationship using a bridge table.

Comment: Yes more than one person can have the same hobby. But I want to record the hobbies of the people specifically.Is it OK if I code the hobbies in another table is it acceptable in the normalization process I just learnt normalization pardon if it's unacceptable.

Comment: you'll need one hobby table and one customerHobby table to track all of the hobbies and all of the hobbies for each customer

Comment: Can I add new attributes;totally new fields to the database?

Comment: Sure, you can add new attributes.   Why wouldn't you be able to?

Comment: I thought it's exceeding the normalization process! :) thank-you  Tab Alleman and Beth

Comment: @laish129 & Tab Alleman 1. Introducing ids & "lookup tables" has nothing to do with normalization. 2. People having more than one hobby does *not* make Hobby a "multivalued attribute". A relation/table *can't have* a multivalued attribute, it has one value per attribute/column per tuple/row. "Multivalued attribute" is something from pre-relational DBMSes & the closest relational analogue is having a list as value when you really want list members as values instead. See reaanb's answer. 3. If you just want 1NF (in that sense of no list) then it's (Person, Name, Hobby) with PK (Person, Hobby).

Comment: My answer was meant to be more practical than theoretical.  I hope I didn't mislead.

Answer (score 1):

From a pure normalization point of view, the new relation's key would be a combination of the original relation's key and the new single-valued attribute.

For example, if you have a relation `(Person PK, Name, Hobbies)`, where Hobbies is a list, you can normalize that into `(Person PK, Name)` and `(Person PK, Hobby PK)`.

The introduction of a surrogate key is a separate issue and while it's often done in practice while normalizing, it's not part of the concept.  Hobby names aren't ideal to use as a key: mostly, they're not unique - there are synonyms, language and syntax variations.  They're also likely to change and not compact.  Thus, a surrogate key may be a good idea.